# SQL Query to export

Tags: sql-server

I have one query to export to an excel file.

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM indisponibilidades WHERE estadoIndisponibilidade = 'ABERTO' OR dataInicio = '" + dataPedido + "' OR dataFim = '" + dataFim + "' ";
```

DataPedido and dataFim are two inputs with this data = 15/09/2014 (for example).

But in some rows dataFim can be a "null" value.

Can i have the query to not export the rows that have null values on dataFim ?

Comment: I answered prior to confirming the RDBMS.  Which are you using?  SQL Server?  Oracle?  MySQL?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server

Comment: What language are you using to construct this query?  C#?  Also, what is the context of data retrieval and parameter setting?

Comment: Yes C#. but i think that i  need to refine my query. The thing is, i need to export all records that estadoIndisponibilidade = "Aberto" and that have been inserted on "dataPedido" or have been closed on "dataFim". Note that dataPedido and dataFim will always be the same data. ex (15/09/2014)

Resuming. Everyday i need to extract a report from the last day. And that needs to include all rows that meet those conditions.


Don't know if you can understand what i'm trying to do

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM indisponibilidades 
WHERE ... your predicate conditions ...
AND dataFim is not null;
```

All you need to do is add on an additional predicate condition to test for non-null values for `dataFim`, specifying `IS NOT NULL`.

Note:  This seems like it could be a one-time data export, so in this case it might not be a big deal for maintainability and scalability, but "`select *`" could break any logic with the data consumer if columns are added.